# What is Unique Value Proposition in UX Design?

Tags: usability, design, value

What is Unique Value Proposition? And what role does it play in User Experience design?

Comment: Please give us some context here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value proposition creates value for customer segment through distinct mix of elements catering to that segment's needs. Value can be quantitative (Price, speed of service) or qualitative ( quality, experience..). Some value propositions may be **innovative and create a new or disruptive choice** to people while some value propositions are similar product/services that can have **an added feature or different attribute** (lower price, different channel, etc..).

- Newness [touchscreen vs normal phone]
- Performance [intel i3 vs intel i7]
- Customization [coca-cola box with names]
- "Getting job done" [finding a plumber in 12 hours]
- Design [philip starck watch]
- Brand/Status  [ a good 6 digit watch]
- Price [ikea]
- Cost reduction, Risk reduction [3rd party call centers]
- Accessibility [Airbnb]
- Convenience / **Usability** [google] are the common themes for value propositions.

[Business canvas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470876417) method can make things easier to understand about VP and the connections of VP to other business elements. UX Designers need to *understand the business variables including customer segmentation and channel* which the right side of the business canvas. Of course, if you can talk about left side, that will make you a UX designer with business affinity.

Defining VP is not always starting from user needs but sometimes other variables like Key Partners, Know-how of the company tries to find a VP that suits the users. I accept the fact that such mentality is a bit different than UX designers' user centered methodologies however; there are also successful business cases that start from the other side :)

[image: Business Canvas Epicenters]

If your company let you to talk about VP as UX Designer (some companies don't), you shall try to share knowledge about user group, their behaviors and share the result of your researches with the team. As stated before, some companies will define Value Proposition for monetizing what they already have and in such equation, UX (Designers&researchers) shall be *advocate for their users and validate assumptions of other business facets*.

Answer (score -2):

**If** you care about your users, you want to design them an experience joyously better than their expectations.

Unfortunately that's an enormous **IF**!

If you achieve this goal the entire experience is a unique value proposition as it's not available elsewhere.

Fortunately, for you, the world of UX designers is littered with dilettantes, posers, programmers and hacks. The user expectation bar is set very low.